# java : xml child not getting deleted using removeChild

Tags: java, xml, dom, tags, removechild

I have a XML as given below. I want to recursively delete the empty tags from the same. As in, once tag f gets deleted tag e should be deleted and as tag e gets deleted tag d is empty and hence that should also be deleted.

```
<Test>
  <a>test</a>
  <b>test</b>
  <c></c>
     <d>
        <e>
           <f> </f>
        </e>
     </d>
</Test>
```

result should be

```
<Test>
  <a>test</a>
  <b>test</b>
</Test>
```

I am able to delete tag  but i am not able to delete tag  as it has blank space. Altough I am able to identify this as a tag to be deleted but when I invoke the removeChild() on its parent it is not getting removed from the XML. In the code while debugging it shows the number of child of e after invoking removeChild() as zero. But still it remains in the xml??

Please can you help me what am I doing wrong.

Please find below my code which I am using.

```
for (Element childElement : toRemove) {
        Node parentNode = childElement.getParentNode();
        System.out.println("Removing null or empty node :: " + childElement.getNodeName());

        if(parentNode!=null){
            NodeList childList = parentNode.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("List of Childer before deleting :: " + childList.getLength());

            parentNode.removeChild(childElement);
            clean(parentNode);

            childList = parentNode.getChildNodes();
            int childCount = childList.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                Node childNode = childList.item(i);
                System.out.println("Childs :: " + childNode);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                Node childNode = childList.item(i);
                if(childNode!=null){
                    System.out.println("Child before deleting :: " + childNode);

                    if (childNode instanceof Element == false){
                        if(childNode.getNodeValue().trim().isEmpty()){
                            System.out.println("found unwanted :: " + childNode.getNodeName());

                            parentNode.removeChild(childNode);
                            i--;
                            childCount--;
                            clean(parentNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            childList = parentNode.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("List of Childer after deleting :: " + childList.getLength());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there is no gap between tags as in instead of <f> </f>, if the tag was like <f></f>, that is without that empty space in the middle. It is able to delete the tag. I even tried to set the value as null or blank for the node before deleting, but that is also not working. Please help !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you are checking only the node value is empty. But it will be better to add more conditions. Child nodes may be not only is Empty, it may be null value also.
`<f/>` will return you null

Therefore make sure that all possibility of null, empty and whitespace could be able to remove the child node.